# How can I share only my CMD Prompt window remotely to other computers?

Tags: windows, command-line, mac, remote-desktop, cmd.exe

I have recently been setting a server and when I start it with its files in the folder with a .bat file it opens up terminal with a command line for it. It is very similar interface to what a regular CMD Prompt. Is there a way I could share **only** this window through MSTSC? Or another way if I provide you with more information, or any external service where you can share your window to a online CMD GUI? If there are any 3rd party extensions to the windows Remote Desktop Connection app that will limit other users from opening files on my desktop that would be an excellent solution as well. If there is a method that is compatible for a Mac to use my CMD Prompt that would be great.

Comment: "When I start it with its files in the folder with a .bat file". What do you mean by this? When you start a bat file on the server, or when you start the server? What what files? Please use the EDIT button and clarify what you are asking.

Comment: Windows supports remote commandline via powershell sessions just fine. But if you're trying to share just this application window with another viewer, most screenshare applications support sharing a single application window.

Comment: There are also a few implementations of SSH daemons for Windows machines...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, the best option and possibly the only one is to this whole process through SSH (Secure Shell). This operates with strong encryption and is meant for this kind of stuff and even more. Basically is specializes in remotely accessing devices or consoles/ssh servers. The program I can use to do this is called PuTTY. It's free and works on all operating systems. It is more advanced but depending on your usage there good be plug-ins like in my case that can use it but simplify your experience. In this case, I was trying to share a console with a Minecraft server. Minecraft servers allow Plug-ins and one connected PuTTY (ssh stuff) and the Minecraft server's console together. Message me for more questions!

Comment: You shouldn't even need a Minecraft plugin for connecting to your box via SSH if you have control of the actual command interface.. just start the ssh service on the box to begin with